# Adding marquee on a playing video in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, video, marquee

I have to develop a simple application in which I have to add a marquee tag on playing video.

Like this please help me how to approach and what kind of tools I need is asp.net

[image: Adding marquee on a video]

Comment: how you show your video in asp.net application, using embed tag or some third party video player?

Comment: embedd tag using html 5

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope this is use full:

```
 In Head tag:
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#divVideo").mouseover(function () {
                    $("#divmarquee").css("bottom", "47px");
                });
                $("#divVideo").mouseout(function () {
                    $("#divmarquee").css("bottom", "21px");
                });
            });   
        </script>

In Body Tag:
   <div id="divVideo" style="width: 30%;">
        <video id="video" width="100%" controls>
        <source id="sovideo" src="ModelVideo/1/video1.mp4" />       
        </video>
        <div id="divmarquee" style="width: 100%; bottom: 47px; position: relative;">
            <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"
                scrolldelay="250" scrollamount="5"><span style="color:White;text-align: center;">Go on... hover over me!</span></marquee>

        </div>
    </div>
```